# SSH reverse tunnel established but unable to connect it

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have a pc at home without a public ip, so I want to establish a reverse tunnel to another server with public ip, then connect to my home pc through the server. However, I can't connect to my pc after established the reverse tunnel, hope someone can help.

Below is the process I used autossh to establish reverse tunnel to server. I modify the public ip to 123.456.78.90.

```
tony@tony-S340MC:~$ autossh -M 6018 -fCNR 0.0.0.0:7020:localhost:22 opc@123.456.78.90

tony@tony-S340MC:~$ sudo netstat -antp | grep 6018
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6018          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7637/ssh            
tcp6       0      0 ::1:6018                :::*                    LISTEN      7637/ssh    
        
tony@tony-S340MC:~$ netstat -a | grep ssh
tcp        0      0 tony-S340MC:49642       123.456.78.90:ssh      ESTABLISHED
```

Then, here's the net status and public port status on server.

```
[opc@srvagent1 ~]$ sudo netstat -antp | grep 7020
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7020            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24261/sshd: opc     
tcp6       0      0 :::7020                 :::*                    LISTEN      24261/sshd: opc     

[opc@srvagent1 ~]$ sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --list-all
public
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 6019/tcp 7020/tcp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

The `GatewayPorts` on the server is `yes`.

After established the reverse tunnel, I connected by another computer. But it was unable to connect it. I have no idea which part goes wrong.

```
$ ssh -v -p 7020 tony@123.456.78.90
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 123.456.78.90 [123.456.78.90] port 7020.
debug1: connect to address 123.456.78.90 port 7020: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 123.456.78.90 port 7020: Connection timed out
```

Edit1 :
I change to use ssh -vv instead of autossh, here's the output on my pc.

```
tony@tony-S340MC:~$ ssh -vv -fCNR 0.0.0.0:7020:localhost:22 opc@123.456.78.90
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 123.456.78.90 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 123.456.78.90 [123.456.78.90] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/tony/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/tony/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tony/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tony/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tony/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tony/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tony/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tony/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tony/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tony/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tony/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tony/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tony/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tony/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 123.456.78.90:22 as 'opc'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none
debug2: compression stoc: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: zlib@openssh.com
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: zlib@openssh.com
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:XxJkoHSa4aJEXoL9Ir5i0lSDBM0TA6E2tx6J6LQd/BQ
debug1: Host '123.456.78.90' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/tony/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/tony/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:IbUI2q2QVZuuRT6rvvdAHciGlzVBRZqPKdCS2EaW3Mc agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/tony/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/tony/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/tony/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/tony/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/tony/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/tony/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000)


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000)


debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/tony/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:IbUI2q2QVZuuRT6rvvdAHciGlzVBRZqPKdCS2EaW3Mc agent
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/tony/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:IbUI2q2QVZuuRT6rvvdAHciGlzVBRZqPKdCS2EaW3Mc agent
debug1: Enabling compression at level 6.
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 123.456.78.90 ([123.456.78.90]:22).
debug1: Remote connections from 0.0.0.0:7020 forwarded to local address localhost:22
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: forking to background
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network

tony@tony-S340MC:~$ debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: remote forward success for: listen 0.0.0.0:7020, connect localhost:22
debug1: All remote forwarding requests processed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
debug1: Connecting to 123.456.78.90 [123.456.78.90] port 7020.
debug1: connect to address 123.456.78.90 port 7020: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 123.456.78.90 port 7020: Connection timed out
```

Your second SSH instance can't make a TCP connection to the tunnel listening port. Specifically, `ssh` sent a TCP connection request to host 123.456.78.90 port 7020, and it never received a response.

The simplest explanation is that there is a firewall blocking these connection requests. The firewall may be on the host that you are running `ssh` on, or it may be on host 123.456.78.90, or it could be on some network device, like a router, in between these two hosts.

This probably has nothing to do with the fact that host 123.456.78.90 port 7020 is the listening port for an SSH tunnel. I don't see anywhing obviously wrong with the `ssh` instance which creates the tunnel. It might work fine if you were able to connect to it.

Comment: I add `sshd:ALL` to `hosts.allows` on my pc then it works. Your replied helps a lot, I forgot my pc may block the connection. Thank you so much.